# Deploy AWS from Codeship Image

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, codeship

## Setup

I did the following steps:

I created with the **IAM Manager** (I guess most of the following permissions are not required/redundant):

- a **group** called codeship with permissions/policies

  - AmazonEC2FullAccess
  - IAMFullAccess
  - AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy
  - AmazonS3FullAccess
  - AWSCodeDeployReadOnlyAccess
  - AWSCodeDeployFullAccess
  - AdministratorAccess
  - AWSCodeDeployRole
  - AWSCodeDeployDeployerAccess
  - AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
- a **user**: Codeship (same permissions) which is part of the above specified group
- a **role**: CodeDeployServiceRole

  - AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy
  - AWSCodeDeployReadOnlyAccess
  - AWSCodeDeployFullAccess
  - AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
  - AWSCodeDeployRole
  - AWSCodeDeployDeployerAccess

Then I created a **E2C Ubuntu Instance** with the tag: `codeship:true` the instance state is running.

Further I created a **S3 bucket** with the name of my app. The bucket has the property setting `Granted: Any Authenticated AWS User` can open/download and view permissions.

Finally I created a **Code Deployment Application** with the name of my app. The application has

- the group: codeship
- the tag: codeship:true
- it deploys to up to all instances at once
- the arn is the one from the IAM role

## error

`No hosts succeeded. (Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS)` which I read is related to missing permissions. The image seems to be transferred correctly from codeship as a zip file. For speed reasons I redeploy the image which is already in the bucket.

## question

What additional settings are required to deploy my app at AWS?